# Twitter Bootstrap's input-prepend with multiline textarea

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter Bootstrap's `input-prepend` class with `<textarea>`. When I set `<textarea>`'s number of rows = 1, all looks fine. But when I set it to any bigger value, element becomes larger than `input-prepend` `span`.

This is the demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/2smRF/

How to set the `span`'s height to `<textarea>`'s height? Can it be achieved using only CSS or I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: `.input-prepend` wasn't built for textareas. Try using a [horizontal form](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) instead.

Comment: Well, I have already used a horizontal form for multiple elements, but in this case I want to add an [icon](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) before `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this would be easily achieved only with CSS, so I threw together a script for you. Please note that it will not work if the user resizes the textarea.

```
var onRes = function(){
    $('.input-prepend').each(function(){
        var $textarea = $(this).find('textarea');
        var $span = $(this).find('span.add-on:eq(0)');
        console.log($span);
        $span.height($textarea.outerHeight()-(parseInt($span.css('padding-top'))+parseInt($span.css('padding-bottom'))+parseInt($span.css('margin-top'))+parseInt($span.css('margin-bottom'))+(parseInt($span.css('border-width'))*2)));
    });
};

$(window).resize(onRes);
onRes();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/d3CAF/)

Comment: That's what I needed! Thank you. If someone is interested, `<textarea>` resized by user can be handled using [jQuery resize plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/).

Comment: @ahawkthomas Yep. You can just pass the `onRes` to the `resize` parameter, and it will work just fine. I just didn't think you would want to use an external plugin, that's why I didn't mention it.

Comment: Thanks again! Just to mention, `resize()` works only on window, and I wrote about resize of the `<textarea>` by user, which is available in Chrome (maybe in other browsers, too).

Comment: @ahawkthomas I know. It works on Firefox and Chrome at the moment. The `resize` I was talking about is one of the plugin's options.